# Using variable with data returned from AJAX call in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, rss

I have searched around and there are questions sort of similar to this one but nothing with an answer that worked for me. I am making a call to an RSS feed with AJAX and then using the data returned to then add the rss feed to a page using jQuery. This works totally fine in Chrome, Safari and amazingly IE but it doesnt work in Firefox. The AJAX call completes and give me a 200 response but the data is never appended to the page and throws no errors in the console. Here is my code

```
$.ajax({
url: '/featured-homesites/rss.xml',
type: 'get',
data:{},
dataType: 'xml',
success: function(data){
    $(data).find('channel item').each(function(){

        var body = "";
        var title       = $(this).find('title').text();
        var neighborhood= $(this).find('category:eq(1)').text();
        var lotSize     = $(this).find('category:eq(2)').text();
        var directLink  = $(this).find('link').text();
        var description = $(this).find('encoded').text();



        body += "<div class='post-body clearfix homesite-post' style='display:inline-block'>";
        body += description;
        body += "</div>";


       $("#homesites").append($("<div />", 
           html:body
           )
       );



    });
},
error: function(){
    $(".timeline").text("Failed to get feed");
}
```

});

Comment: `html:body` is a syntax error. It should not work anywhere.

Comment: Either just `$("#homesites").append(body)` or `$("#homesites").append($("<div />", {html: body}))` .

Comment: Hey Felix, still no dice. I tried both of these and still nothing is added to the page.

Comment: What is even more strange is that the <div> with a class of post-body clearfix homesite-post IS added to the page but the data that is inside the "description" variable is not.